# getting command usage in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I'm have admin permission in my perforce installation. 
I am wondering, if there is a capability for me to see

- all the historical usage of each perforce command
- who invoke those commands
- at what time

I searched thru the internet, and also perforce docs, but couldn't seem to find anything like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is enabling structured logging and then writing a tool to run on the resulting CSV files to provide the reports that you're interested in.

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3088

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the only way.

Comment: There are always other ways -- you could write post-command triggers to implement your own logging, you could scrape the journal and reverse-engineer the command history from db transactions, you could use the plaintext log and parse it, you could do packet inspection, you could set up a p4broker... but the structured log is the easiest.